# Creating YAML using Python: Cloudformation Template

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

Hi I'm trying to create a Cloudformation template using Python. I'm using `yaml` library to do so.

Here's my code:

```
import yaml

dict_file =     {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "ding dong",
    "Parameters": {
        "Environment":{
            "Description": "Environment for Deployment",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources":{
        "Queue": {
            "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
            "Properties":{
                "DelaySeconds": 0,
                "MaximumMessageSize": 262144,
                "MessageRetentionPeriod": 1209600,
                "QueueName": '!Sub "${Environment}-Queue"',
                "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": 0,
                "VisibilityTimeout": 150
            }
        }
    }
}

with open(r'TopicName.yml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(dict_file, file, sort_keys=False)
```

The problem is with Cloudformation tags like `!Sub` as you can see in the key `"QueueName"`. The `!Sub` needs to be outside of quote in the resulting yaml. The resulting yaml this gives looks like this `QueueName: '!Sub "${LSQRegion}-TelephonyLogCall-Distributor"'`

How do I fix this? Any idea? Pleas help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In YAML, an unquoted value beginning with `!` represents a custom type. You're never going to be able to generate that with `yaml.dump` from a simple string value.  You're going to need to create a custom class and an associated [representer](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers) to get the output you want.  For example:

```
import yaml


class Sub(object):
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content

    @classmethod
    def representer(cls, dumper, data):
        return dumper.represent_scalar('!Sub', data.content)


dict_file = {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "ding dong",
    "Parameters": {
        "Environment": {
            "Description": "Environment for Deployment",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Queue": {
            "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue",
            "Properties": {
                "DelaySeconds": 0,
                "MaximumMessageSize": 262144,
                "MessageRetentionPeriod": 1209600,
                "QueueName": Sub("${Environment}-Queue"),
                "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": 0,
                "VisibilityTimeout": 150,
            },
        }
    },
}


yaml.add_representer(Sub, Sub.representer)
print(yaml.dump(dict_file))
```

This will output:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ding dong
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment for Deployment
    Type: String
Resources:
  Queue:
    Properties:
      DelaySeconds: 0
      MaximumMessageSize: 262144
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
      QueueName: !Sub '${Environment}-Queue'
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0
      VisibilityTimeout: 150
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [troposphere](https://pypi.org/project/troposphere/) library too. It supports all the AWS services (which are supported by AWS CloudFormation) and really more pythonic to create CloudFormation template in Python.

I have pasted troposphere code for your CloudFormation template. You can try it out too:

```
from troposphere import Template, Parameter, Sub
from troposphere.sqs import Queue


def get_cfn_template():
    template = Template()
    template.set_version("2010-09-09")
    template.set_description("ding dong")
    template.add_parameter(Parameter(
        "Environment",
        Type="String",
        Description="Environment for Deployment"
    ))
    template.add_resource(
        Queue(
            'Queue',
            DelaySeconds=0,
            MaximumMessageSize=262144,
            MessageRetentionPeriod=1209600,
            QueueName=Sub("${Environment}-Queue"),
            ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds=0,
            VisibilityTimeout=150
        )
    )
    return template.to_json()


print get_cfn_template()
```

Output

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "ding dong",
    "Parameters": {
        "Environment": {
            "Description": "Environment for Deployment",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Queue": {
            "Properties": {
                "DelaySeconds": 0,
                "MaximumMessageSize": 262144,
                "MessageRetentionPeriod": 1209600,
                "QueueName": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "${Environment}-Queue"
                },
                "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": 0,
                "VisibilityTimeout": 150
            },
            "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue"
        }
    }
}
```

Troposphere can convert your code to YAML too.